# How to get ascending dates with time in arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, datetime

I have a list of dates like:

> 20-aug-2018 05:34 pm, 20-aug-2018 06:23 pm, 20-aug-2018 04:03 pm,
>   20-aug-2018 07:20 pm

Now I want to get like this output:

> 20-aug-2018 04:03 pm, 20-aug-2018 05:34 pm, 20-aug-2018 06:23 pm,
>   20-aug-2018 07:20 pm

Comment: sort the list, you will get it.

Comment: list of `dates`? what kind of dates? Or a list of String(s)?

Comment: `List<Date>` or `List<String>`?

Answer (score 1):

If the input is `List<String>`, you can achieve it this way:

1. parse the date string to `LocalDateTime`
2. `LocalDateTime` is comparable, just call `list.sort`

Sample code:

```
// initiate input
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("20-aug-2018 05:34 pm", "20-Aug-2018 06:23 pm", "20-aug-2018 04:03 pm", "20-aug-2018 07:20 pm"));

// build a formatter which is used to parse the string to LocalDateTime
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a")
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);

// sort based on LocalDateTime
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(dateString -> LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter)));
System.out.println(list);
```

output:

```
[20-aug-2018 04:03 pm, 20-aug-2018 05:34 pm, 20-Aug-2018 06:23 pm, 20-aug-2018 07:20 pm]
```

Comment: Nice use of a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `parseCaseInsensitive` method (+1). You are parsing for each comparison. For very long lists this might not be wanted. Instead you may sort the `LocalDateTime` objects and convert back to string after sorting.

Comment: @OleV.V.  Still learning to use java.time package. It's sample code for explain, and not suitable for long list. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Collections.sort(yourList)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list containing date is of type `java.util.Date`, then 
`Collections.sort(yourList)` should work for you

If the list is of type `String`, then you can define your own `comparator` and have the sorting logic in it and pass it to `Collections.sort(yourList, yourcomparator)`

```
public class SortDate {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("20-aug-2018 04:03 pm", "22-aug-2018 07:20 pm",
            "25-aug-2018 06:23 pm", "19-aug-2018 07:20 pm", "08-aug-2018 05:34 pm"));
    Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm aa");
            Date d1 = null;
            Date d2 = null;
            try {
                // Parse the string using simpledateformat. The pattern I have taken based on your code
                d1 = sdf.parse(o1);
                d2 = sdf.parse(o2);
                return d1.compareTo(d2);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // It this return then we have some issue with the string date given
            return -1;
        }

    });
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

}

Comment: If i have pojo class with 10 fields how can i set comparator can u explain please

Comment: @Anilkumar I have updated my answer. Have a look. The code can be shortened if we use Java-8 lambda expressions